# Snake game end game screen

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a snake game.

My problem is that the "Game Over" graphic shows up at the beginning of the game, but I want it to only show when the snake runs into itself.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Snake extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private boolean gameOver; 
private int windowWidth = 800;
private int windowHeight = 600;
private LinkedList<Point> snake;
private int dx;
private int dy;
private Random generator = new Random();
private Point food;
private int points;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Snake();
}

public Snake() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    this.setVisible(true);

    this.createBufferStrategy(2);

    this.addKeyListener(this);

    initGame();

    while(true) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        gameLoop();
        while(System.currentTimeMillis()-start < 40) {
             //do nothing
        }
    }
}

private void initGame() {
    // game variables initialized here
    snake = new LinkedList<Point>();
    snake.addFirst(new Point(20,20));
    growSnake(5);

    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;

    food = new Point(10,10);

    points = 0;
}

private void gameLoop() {
    // game logic

    // move the snake
    moveSnake(dx, dy);

    // check if snake has eaten food
    if(snake.getFirst().equals(food)) {
        moveFood();
        growSnake(3);
        points++;

    }

    // go through walls 

    if (snake.getFirst().x <= 0){
        snake.getFirst().x = windowWidth/10;//go left, wrap right
    }
    else if (snake.getFirst().x >= windowWidth/10){
        snake.getFirst().x = 0;//go right, wrap left
    } 
    else if (snake.getFirst().y <= 0){
        snake.getFirst().y = windowHeight/10;//go top, wrap bottom
    }
    else if (snake.getFirst().y >= windowHeight/10){
        snake.getFirst().y = 0;//go bottom, wrap top
    }

    // check if the snake has hit itself
    for(int n = 1; n < snake.size(); n++) {
        if(snake.getFirst().equals(snake.get(n))) { 
            initGame();
            gameOver = true; 
        }
    }

    drawFrame();
}

private void drawFrame() {
    // code for drawing
    BufferStrategy bf = this.getBufferStrategy();
    Graphics g = null;

    try {
        g = bf.getDrawGraphics();

        // clear the back buffer (just draw a big black rectangle over it)
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

        drawSnake(g);
        drawFood(g);
        drawPoints(g);

        if (gameOver == true){
            gameEnd(g);
        } 


    } finally {

        g.dispose();
    }

    // Shows the contents of the backbuffer on the screen.
    bf.show();

    //Tell the System to do the Drawing now, otherwise it can take a few extra ms until 
    //Drawing is done which looks very jerky
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

private void drawSnake (Graphics g) {
    for(int n = 0; n < snake.size(); n++) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        Point p = snake.get(n);
        g.fillOval(p.x*10, p.y*10, 10, 10);
    }
}

private void moveSnake(int dx, int dy) {
    for(int n = snake.size()-1; n >= 1; n--) {
        snake.get(n).setLocation(snake.get(n-1));
    }
    snake.getFirst().x += dx;
    snake.getFirst().y += dy;
}

private void growSnake (int n) {
    while(n > 0) {
        snake.add(new Point(snake.getLast()));
        n--;
    }
}

private void moveFood() {
    food.x = generator.nextInt((windowWidth/10)-4)+2;
    food.y = generator.nextInt((windowHeight/10)-5)+3;
}

private void drawFood(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(food.x*10, food.y*10, 10, 10);
}

private void drawPoints(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.drawString("points: " + points, 10, 40);
}

private static final Font FONT_LARGE = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 40);

private void gameEnd(Graphics g){

    if (gameOver == true){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(FONT_LARGE);
        g.drawString("Game Over",300, 320);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == 37) {//left
        dx = -1;
        dy = 0;
    } else if(key == 38) {//up
        dx = 0;
        dy = -1;
    } else if(key == 39) {//right
        dx = 1;
        dy = 0;
    } else if(key == 40) {//down 
        dx = 0;
        dy = 1;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Any ideas?` use debugger? Don't write error-prone `if (gameOver == true)` but `if (gameOver)`, instead of active waiting like `while(System.currentTimeMillis()-start < 40) {}` use [Timer/Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: you are not initializing gameOver  set it to false

Comment: @sherif: that's not a problem since booleans by default are false when declared.

Comment: well  just a guess  any way  it makes the code more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void growSnake (int n) {
while(n > 0) {
    snake.add(new Point(snake.getLast()));
    n--;
}
```

}

Because at the beginning the only element of the snake is Point(20,20)

```
snake.add(new Point(snake.getLast()));
```

creates a snake consisting only of the same points. So the

```
growSnake(5);
```

inside initGame() creates 5 points the same as the head.

Then, in

```
private void moveSnake(int dx, int dy) {
for(int n = snake.size()-1; n >= 1; n--) {
    snake.get(n).setLocation(snake.get(n-1));
}
snake.getFirst().x += dx;
snake.getFirst().y += dy;
}
```

you change the value of X and Y by dx and dy, respectively. The problem is, that their initial values are both 0, so the snakes' head does not move. dx and dy values are changed only after key press in

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
int key = e.getKeyCode();

if(key == 37) {//left
    dx = -1;
    dy = 0;
// and so on
```

So, just to sum up - change the default value of dx or dy to 1, so the snakes moves from the beginning of the game.

And one more thing. You can move your snake "back" - if your snake moves to the right and you press the LEFT button - your snake will eat its own head and again - game over.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me do what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues:

- Most importantly, your code does not respect Swing threading rules as you appear to have a long running bit of code, your game loop, being called on the Swing event thread. Don't do that as that could freeze your GUI.
- Instead look up and use a Swing Timer for your game loop.
- Next you're drawing in your GUI using a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. This Graphics object will not persist, and this could lead to inconsistent drawing.
- Instead create a class that extends JPanel or JComponent, and do your drawing in a `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` override method.
- You will want to pull your game logic out of the GUI to simplify your code, and make it easiery to debug. I'd create a SnakeLogic class that holds the position of each snake segment, that moves each segment, that tests for intersection, and then have the GUI class hold an object of SnakeLogic.

I'm sure more to come...

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first movement of the new game, the snake's "head" position is the same position of the body. So... this:

```
if(snake.getFirst().equals(snake.get(n)))
```

Should be:

```
if(snake.getFirst().equals(snake.get(n)) && snake.size() > 6)
```

This way, the condition is only verified when the snake start to move (considering initial size as 5).

Comment: And what if I wanted to include "Game Over" while the snake is still size 5?